# Adding a slave to jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to add a slave in Jenkins. I followed the steps as in https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines .

I added a new node on the Master. But inorder to connect my slave machine, I am not able to find the added node on the slave.

Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

I checked and I do have connect permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to add a new Jenkins slave node is

1. Adds a new node on master (you can do it on the Jenkins web UI)
2. Once step 1 is done, it will show that the node is offline.
3. Remote desktop to slave machine. Browse the URL that says the node is offline **on slave**.
   [image]
4. Clicks Lunch on the page, wait until it shows a confirmation dialog to download/execute `slave-agent.jnpl` file.

   [image]
5. Wait until it shows this popup.
   [image]
6. Clicks File and selects `Install as a Windows Service`